# MATLAB set_param for From Wave Device

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink

How to set the parameters of a from wave device block in a simulink model?

I need to set the "samples per frame" parameter. It must be something like ('Model Name/ From Wave Device','Samples Per Frame',1024) ... but it does not work like this.

Is it possible to set the parameters of this block?

Answer (score 2):

Most Simulink blocks use the dialog prompt as the parameter name, but without the spaces. So in this case, you would use,

```
>> set_param('model/blockName','SamplesPerFrame','1024');
```

Also, since the block accepts a workspace variable as the value, you should set it as a string, so use '1024', not 1024.  One other tip is to use Tab completion, so you could have typed,

```
>> set_param('model/blockName','S[tab]
```

and this would have shown you a list of possible parameters that start with S.

Comment: dear Mike!
THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH!
i have been looking for this for a long time yesterday. i have tried so many combinations, but never the one with " '1024' ". and i also didnt find anything about this in the net ... once again thank you!